How to compile and run in Python LLVM function that does fp128 sum
So, basically I'm trying to compile LLVM code in Python that does sum two fp128 numbers. However the code keeps exiting with error Segmentation fault (core dumped). It's a bit frustrating, because when I change fp128 to double everything works fine. I'm not sure where to look for the solution could smn pls help me. thanks.
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
from __future__ import print_function
from ctypes import CFUNCTYPE, c_longdouble, c_double
import llvmlite.binding as llvm


llvm.initialize()
llvm.initialize_native_target()
llvm.initialize_native_asmprinter()


strmod = """
; ModuleID = "fdadd"
target triple = "unknown-unknown-unknown"
target datalayout = ""

define fp128 @"fpadd"(fp128 %a, fp128 %b)
{
entry:
  %c = fadd fp128 %a, %b
  ret fp128  %c
}
"""


print("-----------------------------------------")
#assembly llvm ir
assmod = llvm.parse_assembly(strmod)
assmod.verify()
print("--parse assembly")
target = llvm.Target.from_default_triple()
target_machine = target.create_target_machine()
engine = llvm.create_mcjit_compiler(assmod, target_machine)
engine.finalize_object()
print(engine)

# Look up the function pointer (a Python int) 
#llvm execution engine call llvm IR function(or dsl function)
func_ptr = engine.get_function_address("fpadd")
print('func_ptr is:',func_ptr)


el_type = c_longdouble

# Run the function via ctypes
cfunc = CFUNCTYPE(el_type, el_type, el_type)(func_ptr)
print (cfunc.argtypes)
print (cfunc.restype)

a = el_type(22)
t = cfunc(a,a) # Segmentation fault (core dumped)
print(t)


